# upload file on laravel 5.7

Tags: php, file-upload, constructor, laravel-5.7

Hello i have some issue on code .dont want to upload file on database and i do all operation adviced here but that not resolved solution on my case and this is the error and code :

```
Argument 2 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse::__construct() must be of the type integer, array given, called in D:\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php on line 203
```

This is balise enctype on my form blade (create.blade.php) 
and this is a method store code inject my data

```
     public function store(cvRequest $request)   {

        if ($request->input('presentation') !== null && $request-> input('titre') !== null ) {
            $cv = new Cv();
            $cv->presentation = $request->input('presentation');
            $cv->title = $request->input('titre');
            $cv->user_id=Auth::user()->id;

            if($request->hasFile('photo')){
               $cv->photo=$request->file('photo')->store('image','public');
            }

            $cv->save();
            session()->flash('enregistrement' ,'Le cv a été bien ajouté' );
            return redirect('cvs',['cv'=>$cv->user->name ]);  
        }
        else{
          return view('cv.create');
            echo "<script>alert('Remplir les Informations necessaire au formulaire !! ')</script>";
        }
    }
```

and i'm already make `php artisan storage:link` on my public file 
and i dont get this issues thanks .

Comment: I thins there is a problem with your redirect code second parameter array type `redirect('cvs',['cv'=>$cv->user->name ])`. T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error This is happend for your route

Try this

```
return redirect('cvs',['cv'=>Auth::user()->name ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is reselved bro with `return redirect('cvs')`  because i'm giving another paramether on methode index

```
public function index() {
    if (!Auth::guest()) {
        $listecv = Cv::where('user_id',[Auth::user()->id])->get();
        return view('cv.index', ['cvs' => $listecv]);   
    }
}
```

and that's return duplicate paramether to my index view but your answer help me to know the origin of problem thanks

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9TCO.png      Yes bro but is said cant vote because my reputation unless 15